# Python / PHP Tesseract Output Optimization tips

Tags: php, python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a python script that scans a receipt and then outputs it into a scanned file.  On the new file use tesseract imagefile outputfile.  I can get good readable text but the parsing shows as below.  Is there a way to line up the purchased item next to the price using tesseract?  My preference is to do it in PHP or Python.

```
WHELE
POODS .4
M

Merchant Name and Address

365 BHCON LS

365 BHCON LS

365 BHCON LS

365 BHCON LS
BROTH CHIC

FLOUR HLHONO

CHKN BRST BNLSS SK
HEAVY CREHH

BHLSHC REOUCT

BEEF GRND 85/1§«
JUICE COF CHSHEU C

i . DOCS PINT ORGRNIC

NP 4.99
NP 4.99
NP 4.99
NP 4.99
NP 2.19
NRuqﬂ1.99
NP 18.80
NP 3.39
NP §.49
NP ’.04
NP ‘f:,99
NP 14.49

HNY HLMONO BUTTER NP 9.99

**** TEX .00 BRL
```

Comment: You could put the picture here? It can improve the reading using the OpenCV to "clean" the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use -psm argument. For more ideas see wiki[1].

[1] https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality